# React Hooks - Change select options when I select an option on another select

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am new in React and I want to change select options of a select when I select an option from another select.

I have this code:

component:

```
 import React from 'react';
 import {useDispatcher, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
 import {getCounty, getLocality } from '../redux/actions/getData';
 import NativeSelect from '@material-ui/core/NativeSelect'; 


export default function UserDetails() {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const state = useSelector(state=>state);

const [county, setCounty ] = React.useState("");
const [locality, setLocality ] = React.useState("");

React.useEffect(() => {
 dispatch(getCounty());
}, []);

return (
 <>
#Select 1
   <NativeSelect
     value={county}
     onChange={e => setCounty(e.targe.value))}
   >
    <option><option>
     {state.county.map(el, key) => (
       <option value={el.id} key={key}> {el.name}</option>
     ))}
    </NativeSelect>
 #Select 2
   <NativeSelect
     value={locality}
     onChange={e=>setLocality(e.target.value)}
   >
    <option><option>
     {state.locality.map(el, key) => (
       <option value={el.id} key={key}> {el.name}</option>
     ))}
    </NativeSelect>
 </>
)
}
```

redux-actions:

```
 export const getCounty = () => (dispatch) => {
   axios.get(URL.COUNTY)
    .then(res => dispatch({
     type: "GET_COUNTY",
     payload: res.data
    }
    .catch(err => {
     console.log(err);
     }
  export const getLocality = (item) => (dispatch) => {
   axios.get(URL.LOCALITY, item)
    .then(res => dispatch({
     type: "GET_LOCALITY",
     payload: res.data
      }
     .catch(err => {
     console.log(err);
     }
```

What I must to do to make the Select 2 to update based on select 1???
Can anybody have an example?
Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

You could just `filter` before rendering the second `select`

```
const countyIds = state.county.map(x => x.id)

//assuming that i.county exists, I don't know how it's called
const filteredLocality = state.locality.filter(i => countyIds.includes(i.county)) 

return(
    {filteredLocality.map(el, key) => (
       <option value={el.id} key={key}> {el.name}</option>
     ))}
)
```

Comment: in redux action in getLocality I get all data and then  filter based on City id?

Comment: You don't really need to filter your reducer data. Just what will be shown inside `select`. You can do this at runtime

Comment: but if I have 50.000 + localities in that table is not slow the performance?

Comment: If you're dealing with large amounts of data consider memoize the value. `useMemo`